# Posterior of parameter for Chinese Restaurant Process

Tags: estimation, posterior, dirichlet-process

I have a [Chinese Restaurant Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_restaurant_process) with (unknown) concentration parameter $\theta$.  After $n$ customers have been seated, I observe the number of non-empty tables and the number of people at each table.  Now I'd like to estimate $\theta$.

How can I estimate $\theta$?  e.g., how do I compute the maximum likelihood estimate for $\theta$, or how can I estimate the posterior distribution on $\theta$, given some reasonable/convenient prior?

---

Crudely, I suppose I could estimate the parameter $\theta$ from the number $t$ of non-empty tables and number $n$ of customers via $\theta \approx t / \log n$, based on a [formula for the expected number of non-empty tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_restaurant_process#Expected_number_of_tables) as a function of $\theta,n$.  However, this doesn't take into account the full data I have, namely, the number of people sitting at each non-empty table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z_i = c$ signify that customer $i$ is seated at table $c$. Let $d_c$ denote the number of customers seated at table $c$. Let $m$ denote the number of tables with at least one customer. Then $\sum_{c=1}^m d_c = n$, since all the customers are seated somewhere. Let $z_{1:n} = (z_1, \ldots, z_n)$ and let $\theta$ denote the concentration parameter.

The distribution of $z_{1:n}$ given $\theta$ can be expressed as
$$
p(z_{1:n}|\theta) = \frac{\theta^m \prod_{c=1}^m (d_c-1)!}{\Gamma(n+\theta)/\Gamma(\theta)} ,
$$
which can be obtained from 
$$
p(z_{1:n}|\theta) = p(z_1|\theta) \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} p(z_{i+1}|z_{1:i},\theta).
$$
Therefore, the likelihood for $\theta$ is given by
$$
p(z_{1:n}|\theta) \propto \frac{\theta^m\,\Gamma(\theta)}{\Gamma(n+\theta)} ,
$$
which depends only on the number of customers and the number of occupied tables.

The posterior distribution for $\theta$ then is
$$
p(\theta|z_{1:n}) \propto p(z_{1:n}|\theta)\,p(\theta) .
$$
I typically use a non-conjugate prior for $\theta$ that is proper but relatively ``open-minded:'' 
$$
p(\theta) = \textsf{Log-Logistic}(\theta|1,1) = \frac{1}{(1+\theta)^2} .
$$
This distribution does not have a finite mean; its median equals 1. I use a Metropolis-Hastings scheme to sample from the posterior.

Answer (score 2):

Mike West wrote a [method for this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d82e/a5fb6d6e2cb9632c38fd0409aaa183b5021d.pdf). The summary is that looked at in the right way, the posterior can be modelled as

$p(α|k, n) ≈ G(a + k − 1, b + γ + log(n))$

Where $a,b$ are priors, $k$ is the number of clusters, $\gamma$ Euler's constant and $n$ your number of observations. Note the approximation, he provides IIRC another method involving mixtures which has the exact conditional.